# Excel vba when adding or deleting sheet in workbook, show/hide button in main sheet

Tags: vba, button

I have a button with a simple macro that deletes certain sheets.
I'd like to show this button only when those sheets are actually there (I can use worksheets.count because I have 2 "permanent" sheets; if > 2 then I know I have a new sheet and I want to show the button to delete it if I want to).

I think I have to use "Workbook.SheetChange event" because "Worksheet.Change event" doesn't seem to work for me in this case.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim foglio_parametri As Worksheet
Set foglio_parametri = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PARAMETRI") 'my main sheet where I want to show/hide the button

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
If Application.Worksheets.Count > 2 Then
    foglio_parametri.CommandButton2.Visible = True
Else
    foglio_parametri.CommandButton2.Visible = False
End If


End Sub
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not use your names as they are in a foreign language I do not understand .

Let's assume the button you are talking about is in a sheet with the name `sheet3` which also has the [codename](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/#Using_the_Code_Name_of_a_Worksheet) `sheet3`. The button itself has the name `CommandButton1`. Let's further assume the *certain* sheets you are talking about have the names `sheet4` and `sheet5` then I would add the following code to the [workbook module](https://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html#Workbook)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet3.HidecmdBtn
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name = "Sheet3" Then
        Sheet3.HidecmdBtn
    End If
End Sub
```

In the [worksheet module](https://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html#Worksheet) of `sheet3` you have the following code

```
Option Explicit

    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()        
        ' Your code goes here

        ' In case your code deletes the sheets you have to hide the button
        HidecmdBtn
    End Sub

    Sub HidecmdBtn()

        Dim Sh As CommandButton
        ' My button is located on sheet 3 and has the name "CommandButton1"
        Set Sh = CommandButton1

        Dim sh1Name As String
        Dim sh2Name As String
        sh1Name = "Sheet4"
        sh2Name = "Sheet5"

        If SheetExists(sh1Name) Or SheetExists(sh2Name) Then
            Sh.Visible = msoTrue
        Else
            Sh.Visible = msoFalse
        End If    

    End Sub
```

In a [normal module](https://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html#videoreg) you have

```
Public Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional wrkBook As Workbook) As Boolean

    If wrkBook Is Nothing Then
        Set wrkBook = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook - whichever appropriate
    End If

    Dim obj As Object

    On Error GoTo HandleError
    Set obj = wrkBook.Sheets(SheetName)
    SheetExists = True
    Exit Function

HandleError:
    SheetExists = False
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much Storax!!! I've been able to adjust your code to my needs and it works perfectly!!!!!!